# Drupal admin menu on/off issue

Tags: 7

I am using drupal 7 . I am having issue with drupal admin menu. When I open new menu this time admin menu disappear and after refresh this page 2-3 times then menu display.

Comment: It sounds like a caching problem. Turn off all caching in Drupal (under performance menu) to see if that eliminates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's cache issue of admin menu, you should disable the caching on client side.

You can do it here: `/admin/config/administration/admin_menu`, under `Performance tab`.

Comment: I forgot that exists that option, thanks @kala4ek.